# Converting char* to unsigned char array C

Tags: c, arrays, char, unsigned-char

I am reading a file that has some data in it. The data is not uniform. But once in a while there might be a line that have a file name and SHA1 sum value in it. I read the data line by line, and then when there is a line with SHA1 sum value, I use strtok, to get data in tokens. And I get SHA1 sum in a variable (e.g: char *hash).

Later in the program, I re-run SHA1 on the same file to get the hash sum (in a variable such as unsigned char hash[20]).  Now I want to compare these to values, but I don't know how to approach that. Should I convert unsigned char array to char* or should I convert char* to unsigned char? or can I compare them without converting? And if conversion is needed, how to do this conversion. I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259962/how-do-i-convert-an-unsigned-char-array-into-a-string-in-c) that sprintf can be used for that, but couldn't do it.

*EDIT:* I realized that this problem was part of another problem I had. I have posted that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406857/comparing-sha-checksum-values-in-c) with code.

Comment: `unsigned char hash[20]` is not a simple variable, it is ARRAY or in other words `hash` is of type `unsigned char *`.

Comment: Conversion from `char` or `unsigned char` to pointer `unsigned char *` is incorrect (but possible), I think you should talk about conversion from `unsigned char` to `char` (it is possible) and placement such elements to array (address pointer by `char*`).

Comment: Your question would be clearer with a code sample. Are you asking how to convert a text series of hex digits into binary data? (or vice versa)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I found out i was asking the wrong question. I have posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406857/comparing-sha-checksum-values-in-c). Don't know if i should link this to that.

Comment: @nEO if this question is no longer relevant  in light of the other question, you can delete it