# How can MD5 algorithm hash a file? What "input" that MD5 used?

Tags: algorithm, hash, md5, rfc

After downloaded file from internet, we always use MD5 or SHA-1 to check integrity of that file. I have a little concern that follow [RFC1312](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321) MD5 use an input is "b-bit message" to hash and give the result is 128 bits out put. But if I give MD5 algorithm a file, not a string, what "b-bit message" did MD5 use to hash?
Thanks for reading my topic.

Comment: The message is the file's content... What exactly is not clear?

Comment: @ Lior Kogan Thanks for answer me, I have checked that. I use 2 text files with different filename and the same content. The hash output is the same. But that is for the simple example. If that is an execution file or ISO file, what "input" that MD5 used to hash?

Comment: Same thing... It is always the file's content.

Comment: Yea, I know that MD5 use the file's content. But I want to know more specific, ex: what is "b-bit message" md5 get from an ISO file.

Comment: Each byte in the file is 8 bits of the message.

Comment: Thanks, a little more clearly. Which is the source that give that information?  I'm reading a book that related to hash algorithm, I want to read more about that. Can you give me a keyword? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416549/getting-hash-of-a-binary-file-c